# Dynamic Inventory Module using Power Shell files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, powershell, nuget

First, I would be much obliged to anyone who can provide links to examples of using VS Power Shell to scaffold/create views/entities/repositories across multiple projects. Examples I have seen so far, everything is lumped into one project.

---

Scenario: User A sells cars, User B sells shoes.
(Users have different Product class property needs,
ie. car ==> Cylinder: int property / shoes==> gender: string

---

Objective: Have both users, through UI, add/modify entities and respective properties that fit their LOB, take that info (prop name and datatype), write to a PS1 file, execute that file script, and have my Domain classes and DAL/Repositories updated to reflect customization, modify database, yet retain existing data.

Can this be done? Any links/examples?

Comment: I can't address your actual question, but it sounds like you are looking for an ERP. This isn't really something you want to build from scratch. I'm not very familiar with them, but a quick google search led to several open source options, including this one. http://www.xtuple.com/postbooks

Comment: He's talking about NuGet in Visual Studio. I've updated the tags.